# Safety stock for lumpy demand

Tags: inventory

[image]

I have a product for which the monthly demand pattern for the last year looks like the following. The product is ordered only 22 days out of 366 days in batch sizes of **272** kgs. Since there are so many months with 0 demand, the demand distribution is heavily skewed. The mean and standard deviation come out to be **634** and **1167** (rounded off), respectively. I have been using this formula (which is the most widely used, I believe) for calculating the safety stock-
$$SS = z_\alpha\sigma_{LTD} $$
where-
$$\sigma^2_{LTD} = \mu_L\sigma_D^2$$
Taking a lead time of **2.8 months** and **z = 2.33** (99% Service Level), I get **SS = 4550 kgs**. Now it doesn't make sense to hold 4550 kgs of inventory when the demand is so lumpy. I know that the above formula is best suited for demands that are approximately normally distributed and understandably results in really high SS values. This is a problem I have been facing with multiple products for which there are several months with very little demand or 0 demand. What is the best way to optimize the inventory for items with lumpy/erratic demand and calculate the safety stock and reorder points for the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like any other demand distribution (e.g., [this one](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/4045/38)), you want to set the *base-stock level* ($S$) equal to $F^{-1}(\alpha)$, where $F(\cdot)$ is the cdf of the lead-time demand distribution and $\alpha$ is the desired service level; and then the *safety stock* is given by $SS = S - \mu_{LTD}$.

(In the case of normal demand, as in your question, $F^{-1}(\alpha) = \mu_{LTD} + z_\alpha\sigma_{LTD}$, so $SS = z_\alpha\sigma_{LTD}$, as you said.)

So, my recommendation is to fit a distribution $\hat{F}$ to your demand data and then set $S = \hat{F}^{-1}(\alpha)$ and $SS = S - \mu_{LTD}$. In your case, the demand distribution will have a point mass at 0.

You can set $\mu_{LTD} = L \mu_D$ and $\sigma_{LTD}^2 = L\sigma^2_D$ (where $\mu_D$ and $\sigma_D$ are the mean and SD of the demand per period and $L$ is the lead time). But you could also try to estimate these directly from the data, e.g., estimate the mean and SD of the demand over an $L$-period stretch.

By the way, there is some literature on this topic. A Google search for "inventory optimization lumpy demand" or something similar will turn up some hits that are probably more rigorous and general than my approach.

Comment: So the probability mass function is as follows: {'0'= 0.67, '815.85' = 0.167, '2447.5' = 0.083, '3535.35' = 0.083}. I can construct a discrete cumulative distribution function using this pmf. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Since the data is so sparse, would it be feasible to fit a continuous distribution without overestimating the mean and variance?

Comment: @NishantKumarGupta, would you please, see this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/udas0z8xodimtqr/test.jpg?dl=0). According to your data, neither of the distribution functions can fit the demand data exactly and estimating of the mean and SD is too hard. I think the method that LarrySnyder610 mentioned should be a good point.

Comment: @A.Omidi I can construct a discrete pdf from this data to get $F(x) = 0.916$ for $2447\leq x<3535$ and $F(x) = 1$ for $x \geq3535$. Suppose I choose a 95% service level, The inverse using this cdf would say that $2447\leq x<3535$. If I take x to be equal to the mean of the two values i.e. $x=2991$, this would act as my base-stock level S. I can then subtract the mean demand (634) to get SS = 2357. Is this the approach that LarrySnyder610 is suggesting? I agree that fitting a continuous distribution would be way off considering the sparsity of the data

Comment: Actually, what I was proposing was fitting a continuous distribution. I suppose you could use either approach. If you use the discrete approach, you are basically pretending that the demand can _only_ equal 815.85 or 2447.55 or 3535.35, which I assume is not correct either. Under both approaches there will be some significant inaccuracies. I think the underlying issue is that you simply don't have enough data to use it reliable for inventory management. I assumed that the data set you posted was just a snippet, but is this the full extent of the data?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all the data I have. As for the demand, you can observe that they are all multiples of 272, which is the batch size of the production campaign. So in 2019-06, there were 3 batches, 13 batches in 2019-09 and so on. Could we perhaps draw some conclusions from the frequency of the batches which I mentioned in the question was 22/366 days?

Comment: Yes, that definitely seems like a reasonable approach. If you don’t have more data, that’s too bad but that’s the reality. As long as you’re clear eyed about the accuracy of the results. One other note, it’s also reasonable to use other forecasting techniques other than simply fitting a distribution to the scant data.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I am a bit confused. Do we exclude periods of 0 demand while calculating mean, standard deviation and the CDF? Suppose these periods of 0 demand were not random occurences but happened because of planned downtime such as maintenance scheduling etc. Including 0 demand would underestimate the mean and overestimate the std. deviation. This is a problem I can see when production is done in batches (as is the case here) and not the whole year. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @NishantKumarGupta, Would you tell please, does the factory have to produce the whole order (e.g. $3535.35$) on 2019-09 and deliver to the customer? I mean could you produce and store the product in the previous months and then (on 2019-09) deliver the whole order to the customer?

Comment: @A.Omidi This is the production schedule. The company is a pharmaceuticals company. So what they do is run the production in batches. Here, it would mean that they would produce a given quantity (say $815.85$) in 3-4 days, store the product in a warehouse and then use that inventory to serve customers for 2-3 months. They have to rely on forecasts a lot for such a slow-moving product. I assume that they expected the demand to increase in the later months (09,10,11..) which is why they produced such a huge quantity in 2019-09. I don't have data about the actual customer demand.

Comment: @NishantKumarGupta, thanks. As you mentioned, I think you can smooth the company demands in the planning horizon, in this case, 12 months. If you could produce and store the products to service the customers, one practical approach might be as this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzgnpw7765oi4vq/smooth%20data.jpg?dl=0). Based on the smoothing data you can fit a better distribution to calculate the **SS**. I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: @A.Omidi that seems like a good strategy. May I ask how you smoothed out the demand and obtained the goodness of fit parameters? Thanks!

Comment: @Nishant, thanks. I try smoothing the data by dividing them based on available months till to delivery month. For example, we need to deliver $815$ items in the third month and dividing this demand based on the batch size during these months. This method helps produce little batch instead of the whole delivery and may be reliable to chase customer demand. About the second question, the goodness of fit analysis was created using Excel and Minitab software. :)

Comment: @NishantKumarGupta I would say that the 0s should be part of the data set, not separated out. You don't need the mean and SD explicitly, you only need the cdf, and the 0s are part of that cdf. As for "planned" vs. "unplanned" 0s that's a trickier issue. I think you are in uncharted waters to some extent.

Comment: These papers are a bit relevant. They discuss "0s" in the context of supply, not demand, but maybe some of the insights are useful to you. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/nav.20228 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054810001681